# Prove that $ \langle x^2+y^2+z^2 \rangle $ is a prime ideal of $ \mathbb{R}[x, y, z]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Prove that $ \langle x^2+y^2+z^2 \rangle $ is prime ideal of $ \mathbb{R}[x, y, z]$

I try to find an integral domain such that quotient ring is isomorphic to integral domain but I can't.

Actually I am beginner to learn ring of polynomial with more than one variable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Cannot you just try the definition : suppose $p(x,y,z)q(x,y,z) = m(x,y,z)(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ and try to show that $p$ or $q$ is a multiple of $(x^2+y^2+z^2)$?

Comment: In addition, $\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]$ is a UFD, so this principal ideal is prime if and only if the element is prime, if and only if it is not a unit and irreducible...

Comment: @Arturo Magidin Intuition says $x^2+y^2+z^2$ is irreducible but how do you prove formally

Comment: A quite general method is to say that if it is a prime ideal then $Frac(\Bbb{R}[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^2+z^2)) =  \Bbb{R}(x,y)[z]/(f)$ where $f=x^2+y^2+z^2$ is the $ \Bbb{R}(x,y)$-minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. It is obvious $f$ is irreducible so $\Bbb{R}(x,y)[z]/(f)$ is a field and it suffices to check that $f  \Bbb{R}(x,y)[z] \cap \Bbb{R}[x,y,z] = (x^2+y^2+z^2)\Bbb{R}[x,y,z]$ to obtain that $\Bbb{R}[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ is a subring of that field thus it is an integral domain and $(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ is a prime ideal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\left<x^2+y^2+z^2\right>$ is not a prime ideal, there should exist $g,h\in \mathbb{R}[x,y,z]$ s.t. $x^2+y^2+z^2\mid gh$, $x^2+y^2+z^2\nmid g,h$.

Since $\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]$ is a UFD, this implies there exist nonunit $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]$ s.t. $\alpha\beta=x^2+y^2+z^2$.

$\alpha,\beta\neq 0$, so $\alpha,\beta$ not being unit implies $\deg(\alpha),\deg(\beta)>0$. Since $\deg(\alpha\beta)=2$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is integral, $\deg(\alpha)+\deg(\beta)=2\Rightarrow \deg(\alpha)=\deg(\beta)=1$.

We can write $\alpha=ax+by+cz$.

Now, observe that for every $(x,y,z)\neq(0,0,0)$, $x^2+y^2+z^2\neq 0$. Since we can find nontrivial $(x,y,z)$ s.t. $ax+by+cz=0$, this is a contradiction.